# Como ativar animação somente no botão clicado e não em todos

Tags: javascript, jquery

sou novo em desenvolvimento e estou com um problema.

Tenho alguns "cards" cada um com uma imagem, uma descrição e um botão que ao ser clicado faz a descrição aparecer. Só que quando eu clico em um botão para mostrar a descrição ele mostra a de todos. Segue abaixo um link com o código que estou utilizando.

```js
$(".bt-card").click(function(){
 $(".property-information").toggleClass("property-information-active");
 $(".bt-card").toggleClass("bt-card-active");
});
```

```css
.property-card{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 .property-image{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
 .property-information{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  border: solid 1px #777;
  border-top: none;
  font-weight: lighter;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  color: $white_color;
  .title-property{
   display: block;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #333;
   z-index: 3;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   transition: all 300ms ease-out;
   &:hover,
   &:active{
    color: #FFF;
   }
  }
  .property-item{
   margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .property-item,
  .bt-ctn{
   z-index: 3;
  }
  &::before{
   content: '';
   top: -45%;
   left: 8%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 90%;
   height: 360px;
   transform: rotate(20deg);
   background-color: rgba(135, 178, 0, 0.85);
   z-index: 0;
  }
 }
 .property-information-active{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 }
}

.bt-card{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 font-size: 28px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all .3s ease-out;
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: rgba(135, 178, 0, 0.85);
 z-index: 5;
}
.bt-card-active{
 transform: rotate(225deg);
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="property-card">
  <a class="property-image" href="#">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x360" />
  </a>
  <div class="property-information">
    <a href="#" class="title-property">Residencial Mallet</a>
    <span class="property-item">Residencial Mallet</span>
    <span class="property-item">Residencial Mallet</span>
    <div class="bt-ctn">
      <a href="#" class="bt bt-pri-overlay">Saiba Mais</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="bt-card">+</span>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte seletor para chamar individualmente o botão clicado e o elemento do mesmo bloco `article`:

```
$(".bt-card").click(function(){
    $(this)
   .toggleClass("bt-card-active")
   .closest("article")
   .find(".property-information")
   .toggleClass("property-information-active");
});
```

Para fechar os outros ao clicar em um:

```
$(".bt-card").click(function(e){

   $(".bt-card")
   .not(e.target)
   .removeClass("bt-card-active")
   .closest("article")
   .find(".property-information")
   .removeClass("property-information-active");

    $(this)
   .toggleClass("bt-card-active")
   .closest("article")
   .find(".property-information")
   .toggleClass("property-information-active");

});
```

Comment: Obrigado, Teria como quando eu clicasse em um outro fechar o que esta aberto ?

Comment: @DiegoJesus Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado mesmo! Me ajudou bastante!

Comment: @DiegoJesus De nada bro! QQ coisa tamos aí